# .NET MVC 3 Search in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm new to .NET. I'm trying to do something very simple.
I would like to perform a search on a Model in my controller and retrieve the first entity returned :

```
var cercueils = from y in db.Cercueils select y;
cercueils = cercueils.Where(z => z.Type.ToUpper().Contains(dr[13].ToUpper())
          || z.AncienType.ToUpper().Contains(dr[13].ToUpper()));
Cercueil cercueil = cercueils.First();
```

But this is not good, as it throws an error :

```
Le type de nœud « ArrayIndex » de l'expression LINQ n'est pas pris en charge dans LINQ to Entities.
```

(Google translate: "the node type of the LINQ expression arrayIndex n is not supported in LINQ to Entities")

How can I achieve that ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you translate the error you're getting from french to english? That will made it more readible.

Comment: You may be constraining your question too much - this isn't so much an MVC questions as a LINQ question.

Comment: Google translate: "the node type of the LINQ expression arrayIndex n is not supported in LINQ to Entities"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Linq doesn't know how to execute 'dr[13]' in the context of deferred execution...
try the following:

```
var tmp = dr[13].ToUpper();
var cercueils = from y in db.Cercueils select y;
cercueils = cercueils.Where(z => z.Type.ToUpper().Contains(tmp)
          || z.AncienType.ToUpper().Contains(tmp));
Cercueil cercueil = cercueils.FirstOrDefault();
```

Also, I usually recommend FirstOrDefault with a null check afterwards :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Where()` clause (`z => z.Type.ToUpper().Contains(dr[13].ToUpper())` etc.) cannot be translarted into the SQL-type query, so Linq to Entities gives you the aforementioned error.

You can fix the error in twi ways: either transform your expression so that Linq to Entities is able to generate the query (I had some success with `IndexOf()` instead of `Contains()`), or just download the entire table and perform the search locally (obviously, the second option will hamper performance):

```
var cercueils = (from y in db.Cercueils select y).ToList(); // load the entire dataset
cercueils = cercueils.Where(z => z.Type.ToUpper().Contains(dr[13].ToUpper())
      || z.AncienType.ToUpper().Contains(dr[13].ToUpper()));
Cercueil cercueil = cercueils.First();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var cercueils = (from y in db.Cercueils
                        where y.blahblah = blahblah
                        select y).FirstOrDefault();
```